# Error in Eclipse Android R.java file in appcompat

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I start to learn Android Programming but i have one problem that i'm not solving. I install eclipse and SDK Manager, i install Platform, build-tol and all necessary, but when i create one project all line of code have an error, and in the project auto-generated appcompat_v7 in R.java file. I Also reinstall eclipse and the SDK and the necessary tools but i have the error too...

[image]

[image]

How cna i solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Try to clean the projects. `Project -> Clean`

Comment: I try but this delete the R.java file in appcompat_v7 and continue to give errors in projects

Comment: goto your appcompat project and goto the libs folder and copy the v7 jar file and place it in your libs folder in your project and right click to add to build path and refresh..thats all..

Answer (score 0):

For R.java Errors do one of the following:
1- Right-click on the project then Refresh
2- Select Project → Clean. Eclipse will rebuild the project from scratch, which often results in an error-free build.
3- Select Window → Run Android Lint. This can often pull the pieces of your project together. 
4- Delete your gen directory and when Eclipse rebuilds, it will create a new gen directory with a fully-functional R class.

Comment: i try that i delete also .metadata from the workbench and it solved some error, but when it recreate the appcompat project it not create the R.java files and in the project it give errors....

Comment: Make sure you have latest versions installed of SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools and SDK Build-tools and try again again.

Comment: i have all latest versions